# How to prove equally likely steps of the Hailstone sequence (collatz sequence)

Tags: probability, number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Consider the condensed collatz conjecture

if $x$ odd then $f(x)=(3x+1)/2$: if $x$ even $f(x) = x/2$: Continue until $x = 1$ or find an $x$ in the natural numbers that will not hit $1$.

The equation is condensed in this way because originally every $3x+1$ step would be trivially immediately be followed by a $x/2$ step under iteration.

My question is what would go into a proof or disproof that on average for a natural number $x$ each step in the iteration is equally likely I.e. each step has $50\%$ probability in the long run?

Comment: It should be $(3x+1)/2$.

Comment: Every other odd number is an ascender where (3x+1)/2 is odd. The other odd numbers are descenders, which require one or more division by 2.

Comment: This doesn't explain behavior over iteration in the long term but just over the first few steps.

Comment: Iterate with $2^{1000000}-1$ and you will have a million ascenders before the first descender.

Comment: Again can be countered by 2^{1000000} has a million descender and no ascender. I know that discussing single examples is not enough to show what i asked i.e. long term behavior over all integers.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've never liked the condensed collatz function as you give it because if $x$ is odd, then two calculations are performed, but if $x$ even, then only one calculation is done. One cannot really count "steps", i.e., how many operations it takes to reduce to 1.

That aside, to answer your question: note that $x<\frac{3x+1}{2}$, so if each step were equally likely, $n$ would increase and never reduce to 1. It seems to me, that for any number (especially large ones), there have to be more steps with $n$ even in order for the sequence to stop.

Comment: Actually if both were equally likely and we take x through both we get (3x+1)/4 suggesting an average decrease if both are likely.  this is the reason I'm using the condensed form in this question.

Comment: We can assume $x$ is odd. If we take $x$ through both, then $3x+1$ must have been divisible by 4, a case that is only 50% likely. I think half the time $\frac{3x+1}{2}$ will be odd.

Comment: then take it through 8 steps. we still see that if each were equally likely then there is an average decrease. I don't think this one is solvable easily. you can always take a number through 2k steps to show that it decreases on average.

Comment: I agree that a number will always decrease after enough steps. It is just my opinion that the decrease is from the $x/2$ step occurring more frequently.

Comment: My statement is that it's not necessary for those steps to occur more often for a number to decrease on average (this still allows for rare divergent cases). Your statement doesn't offer any additions to how to prove what I asked but you simply stated a opinion.  and did you just agree to an unproven conjecture?